# Flutter TextFormField validator text is too long

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have this TextFormField inside a small container. The problem is my validator message text it too long for the container so it just get cut.

How can I get around this problem ? I need the user able to read the whole text. How to make the message moving as like a running text or just fit the text by making making the font size smaller automatically ?

I dont know, please help me. Any suggestion will do for me

Thank you

```
                TextFormField(
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  controller: _newForeignController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    fillColor: Colors.black26,
                    filled: true,
                    hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white24),
                    hintText: "New word here",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'This is a warning that too long to display in the app';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: can you try setting error style with overflow = TextOverflow.ellipsis inside InputDecoration?

Comment: @Rahul where should I put the `overflow = TextOverflow.ellipsis` ?. I cant find it in the `TextFormField`

Comment: just edit these lines as u prefer inside InputDecoration.. & u r good to go
  errorMaxLines: 3,
  errorStyle:const TextStyle(fontSize:45),

Comment: Search for errorStyle property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `errorMaxLines` as per your need, It indicates how many line can error text occupy:

```
TextFormField(
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    controller: _newForeignController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.black26,
                      filled: true,
                      hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white24),
                      hintText: "New word here",
                      errorMaxLines: 6,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return 'This is a warning that too long to display in the app,This is a warning that too long to display in the app,This is a warning that too long to display in the app';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I dont know we have that property. Silly me